# redirect execwait result to a file nsis

Tags: nsis

Hi how can I redirect result from `ExecWait` command

I was trying

```
ExecWait '"$INSTDIR\MyApp\isql.exe localhost:$INSTDIR\MyApp\tts.fdb -U SYSDBA -p password -i $INSTDIR\MyApp\src\dbfile.sql >>$INSTDIR\logfile.txt"'
```

But no luck, it did not create any log file. Any ideas? 
I do not want to use any additional libraries.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ExecWait is just a thin wrapper around the CreateProcess API and it does not support redirection.

The easy way to get redirection is to use cmd.exe/%comspec% with the /c switch and one of the exec plugins, nsExec, ExecDos or ExecCmd: `"$sysdir\cmd.exe" /c "c:\your\app.exe" /param1 /param2 > "c:\file.txt"`

If you search for "comspec" on the [NSIS forum](http://forums.winamp.com/forumdisplay.php?forumid=65) you will find many threads about this...